# Can "type-id" for reinterpret_cast< type-id > be a variable?

Tags: c++, casting

Currently I have this for a sorting function:

```
bool operator()( CVParent* lhs, CVParent* rhs ) 
{
  double dFirstValue  = reinterpret_cast< CVChild * >( lhs )->GetValue( m_lFeature );
  double dSecondValue = reinterpret_cast< CVChild * >( rhs )->GetValue( m_lFeature );
  ....
}
```

Right now the type-id is hardcoded as CVChild* but can it be a parameter? I don't want to be writing a function for every derived classes of CVParent.

Edit:
I have made changes based on Rost's recommendation:

```
class Compare_Functor
{
public:

    Compare_Functor( const long& lFeature, const bool& bIsAscending )
    {
        m_lFeature = lFeature;
        m_bIsAscending = bIsAscending;
    }

    template <class T> 
    bool operator()( CVParent* lhs, CVParent* rhs ) 
    {
      double dFirstValue  = reinterpret_cast< T * >( lhs )->GetValue( m_lFeature );
      double dSecondValue = reinterpret_cast< T * >( rhs )->GetValue( m_lFeature );
      ....
    }

private: 

    long m_lFeature;
    bool m_bIsAscending;
}
```

Current Usage (how to do revised the stl sort function call?):
    std::sort( m_pList, m_pList+GetCOunt(), Compare_Functor(lFeature, TRUE) );

I fixed the code. Thank you for everyone's help!

```
template <class T>
class Compare_Functor
{
public:

    Compare_Functor( const long& lFeature, const bool& bIsAscending )
    {
        m_lFeature = lFeature;
        m_bIsAscending = bIsAscending;
    }

    bool operator()( CVParent* lhs, CVParent* rhs ) 
    {
      double dFirstValue  = reinterpret_cast< T * >( lhs )->GetValue( m_lFeature );
      double dSecondValue = reinterpret_cast< T * >( rhs )->GetValue( m_lFeature );
      ....
    }

private: 

    long m_lFeature;
    bool m_bIsAscending;
}


//Usage
std::sort( m_pList, m_pList+GetCOunt(), Compare_Functor<CChild>(lFeature, TRUE) );
```

Comment: Can you give your reasons why you want to use `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: 1. IIRC (I haven't checked it now) it can be template argument. 2. Are you sure you want to have `reinterpret_cast` (in most cases casts are not the best style of programming and one should avoid them unless they are really needed)?

Comment: No, I want to use reinterpret_cast but pass in the type to be cast to as a variable.

Comment: When you say _variable_, you mean a template parameter? If so, how would the value of that parameter be determined?

Comment: If I want to sort derived classes, I would need to rewrite the function for every derived classes:
reinterpret_cast< CVChild * >(lhs)

reinterpret_cast< CVChild2 * >(lhs)

reinterpret_cast< CVChild3 * >(lhs)

Comment: You can't. C++ doesn't have any introspection functionality, so you can't get the type of a variable and use that to create new variables or to typecast.

Comment: If all derived classes returns the same type, you should use a virtual function in the base class that the derived classes override.

Comment: You need to revisit your design if you are relying on determination of type of an object.It breaks the [Liskov subsitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Comment: Do not use `reinterpret_cast`. It is a low-level machine-dependent construct for bit-pattern manipulation. It is not guaranteed to work for casting base to derived (or for nearly anything else). It is guaranteed to break in multiple-inheritance situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to pass any dynamic (known in run time only) type to `reinterpret_cast`. It must be static (known in compile time).

You could use templates as mentioned in other answer, but you will need to explicitly set the type to cast for each function call because compiler will not be able to deduce it from call expression:

```
template <class T> struct Functor
{
   bool operator()(CVParent* lhs, CVParent* rhs) { ... }
};

CVParent p1, p2;
...

// Usage
Functor<CVChild1>().operator()(&p1, &p2);
Functor<CVChild2>().operator()(&p1, &p2);
Functor<CVChild3>().operator()(&p1, &p2);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have made changes but not sure how I actually pass in the type of the child class because I'm using std::sort to call the functor:

Comment: std::sort( m_pList, m_pList+GetCOunt(), Compare_Functor(lFeature, TRUE) );

Comment: In this case you need to make entire functor template, not only operator(). I'll edit the answer.

Comment: ahh... I got it now, I should use class template and not function template:

std::sort( m_pList, m_pList+GetCOunt(), Compare_Functor<child>(lFeature, TRUE) );

Is this correct?

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm not very familiar with template usage. :)

Comment: @user1679306 And please revisit your usage of `reinterpret_cast` as many people mentioned here. Looks like you actually need `dynamic_cast` or `static_cast`.

Comment: Yes, noted. Will use dynamic cast instead. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use a [template](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/) in your implementation.

```
template <class Type>
bool operator()( CVParent* lhs, CVParent* rhs ) 
{
  double dFirstValue  = reinterpret_cast< Type * >( lhs )->GetValue( m_lFeature );
  double dSecondValue = reinterpret_cast< Type * >( rhs )->GetValue( m_lFeature );
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using templates, but class templates, not function templates. This would make it more natural to use in standard library algorithms and contaiers:

```
template <typename T>
struct CVFuntor 
{
  bool operator()( CVParent* lhs, CVParent* rhs ) const
  {
    double dFirstValue  = reinterpret_cast<T*>( lhs )->GetValue( m_lFeature );
    double dSecondValue = reinterpret_cast<T*>( rhs )->GetValue( m_lFeature );
    ....
  }
};
```

Then

```
typedef CVFunctor<CVChild> ParentToChild;
typedef CVFunctor<CVOtherChild> ParentToOtherChild;

....

ParentToChile p2ch;
bool b = p2ch(SomeParentPtr1, SomeParentPtr2);
```

You should reconsider your use of `reinterpret_cast`. It seems to me that a checked call to `dynamic_cast` is more suitable here:

```
T* t = dynamic_cast<T*>( lhs);
if (!t) return false;
```